# MySQL insert id values from other table into matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

I want to normalize my tables:

```
products
id | name | manufacturer | manufacturer_id

manufacturers
id | name
```

I require a query to update products.manufacturer_id where products.manufacturer = manufacturers.name (I will then delete products.manufacturer)

Many thanks for your time

Tom

Comment: What you haven't said is that `products.manufacturer` is not set, and `products.manufacturer_id` is. Correct?

Comment: On the contrary - I am switching from name to id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
update products INNER JOIN manufacturers
set products.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
where products.manufacturer = manufacturers.name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update products p
   set p.manufacturer_id =
       (select m.id from manufacturers m where m.name = p.manufacturer)
```